# How to increase Hover Space in CSS

Tags: css, menu, dropdown, mouseover, spacing

I am trying to keep some space between the Navigation Button (text) and the Dropdown Menu, so it looks good and is positioned under the black Navigation bar.  There is no way to mouseover the Dropdown Menu with the extra space that I added (and wanted) between the two elements.

Here is what end-result should be: https://csswizardry.com/demos/maximising-hit-area/ Not sure how to get there...

HTML

```
  <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Services&nbsp; <i class="down"></i></button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <div class="column_test">
            <a href="#">Item 1</a>
            <a href="#">Item 2</a>
            <a href="#">Item 3</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column_test">
            <a href="#">Item 4</a>
            <a href="#">Item 5</a>
            <a href="#">Item 6</a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
/* The dropdown container */
.dropdown {
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 37px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

/* Dropdown button */
.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 12px; 
  font-weight:300;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #FFFFFF; /* Nav text color */
  background-color: inherit;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn:hover {
  color: blue;
}

/* Dropdown content - 6 item box (hidden by default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  width:400px;
  top:70px;
  padding-bottom:7px;
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  color: #000000;
  float: none;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this one myself by adding height:65px to .dropdown.dropbtn which increased the hover space.  Hope this helps someone else.